# Avoid repeating column header in JRXML

Tags: jasper-reports

How can I avoid the column name repeating in JRXML? Is there any attribute for avoiding having the column header in each page when generating a report using JRXML and Jasper?

Answer (score 20):

If the header will always be on a specific page (e.g. the first page), you can add

```
<printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}==1]]></printWhenExpression>
```

to the band, which will make it only print on page 1. `PAGE_NUMBER` is an inbuilt variable that is automatically incremented as the report is generated.

Comment: Besides, in our report Jasper leaves a narrow row (row height 5) instead omitting the column headers entirely.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo. That 5 unit gap sounds strange; What version of Jasper are you using?

Comment: 4.5.1. Using JRParameter.IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION did the trick for me.

Comment: @genericjon can u please provide Java specific code of the same?

Comment: This solution doesn't work when you have dynamic elements on the first page that might push the first appearance of the column header to the second page of your report.

Comment: @m00hk00h Hence the first sentence `*If* the header will always be on a specific page`

Answer (score 20):

Set The following parameter into your java code if your using java to fill the report:

```
parameters.put(JRParameter.IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION, Boolean.TRUE);
```

Answer (score 9):

In jasper report tag put
    `isIgnorePagination="true"`

Answer (score 2):

Another option:
http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRParameter.html#IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION

"If set to true the report will be generated on one long page."

Answer (score 2):

An easier option is to choose the "Table Header" to be used for the header instead of "Column Header".

I also faced same problem and that solution worked for me.

Comment: It's nearly impossible to make out what you're trying to say. We understand that English is not your first language, but please put some effort into what you're typing.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any attribute for avoiding having the column header in each page when generating a report using JRXML and Jasper?

You can use **`isPrintInFirstWholeBand`** property and move columns header to the `Group Header` band (or `Title` band if you have not group).

Answer (score 0):

Create a dummy group and use the Group Footer Band.. That did the trick for me since the summary band was already used..

Answer (score 0):

I tried:

```
     params.put(JRParameter.IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION, Boolean.TRUE);
```

**But**, I got a long page 1/1, that it is not easy to print without getting any row splitted in the half.

Instead, I choosed the second approach from iReport designer:

1-create new empty cells in Table Header.

2-Move the cells(Header Cells) from the Column Header to Table Header, bydragging one by one.

3-Delete the empty cells in the Column Header.

4-Design the new cells background by selecting them choosing Backcolor from properties, or selecting the column (table) to define style, choose `table 1_CH` from properties.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would just avoid using the column header whenever I can. For some reason group headers provide users with a lot more options and flexibility.
So even if I don't use groups in my report I create a "constant group" that uses a constant expression as `groupExpression` and then use this group's header as the report's column header.

With a constant expression like `true` the group never changes because it's independent from the data set. And because it never changes it not only won't ever be printed twice automatically, it will also provide the *option* to be reprinted on each page (among other options) by simply checking the checkbox in JasperSoft studio (or adding the corresponding attribute to the group tag).

The advantages over deactivating pagination or using a page dependent `printWhenExpression` are:

- independent from the page number that the header appears on for the first time (a title page or dynamic content might push the first appearance to the second or third page)
- allows pagination (nice for exporting as PDF with page headers/footers)
- offers more options than standard column header

Downsides

- adds complexity to the report

Here is an example for a non-repeating constant group header definition in JRXML:

```
<group name="columnHeaderGroup" isReprintHeaderOnEachPage="false">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA["a constant"]]></groupExpression>
    <groupHeader>
        <band height="20">
            <!-- any column header content like Static Texts or Text Fields -->
        </band>
    </groupHeader>
</group>
```

Note that you could also simply remove `isReprintHeaderOnEachPage="false"` as this the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

We can use below line also to avoid repeated columnHeader

Comment: <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[($V{PAGE_NUMBER}.equals(new Integer(1))? Boolean.TRUE:Boolean.FALSE)]]></printWhenExpression>