# JasperReports reprint table header when table footer in next page

Tags: jasper-reports

I have some problem with my jasper table. If count of elements in table more then 18, table footer carry on next page, but table header does not reprint. How to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `Column header` instead of `Table header`.

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347020/avoid-repeating-column-header-in-jrxml)  seems to be the reverse of your question.